# Google Maps Api: polygoneCoords = [javascriptvariable];

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can i read follwing line:

```
var polygoneCoords = [javascriptvariable];
```

instead of

```
var polygoneCoords = [new google.maps.LatLng(49.91727104462425, 10.872366428375244) ,new google.maps.LatLng(49.91740920888044, 10.872366428375244)];
```

Of course I have defined "javascriptvariable", but i ony get :

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google.maps.Polygon object can contain one or more paths. Each path is an array (or MVCArray) made of coordinates. Every coordinate is, in turn, a google.maps.LatLng object or a LatLngLiteral.

This means that you can either declare it as

```
var polygoneCoords = [new google.maps.LatLng(49.91727104462425, 10.872366428375244),new google.maps.LatLng(49.91740920888044, 10.872366428375244)];
```

or as

```
var polygoneCoords = [{lat:49.91727104462425,lng: 10.872366428375244},{lat:49.91740920888044, lng: 10.872366428375244}];
```

Any other path declaration will yield the error you're seeing now.

I hope your polygon gets more than two vertexes, or it will be seriously underdimensioned.

So, regarding your question in particular, you're free to use the second syntax and do:

```
var javascriptvariable = [{lat:49.91727104462425,lng: 10.872366428375244},{lat:49.91740920888044, lng: 10.872366428375244}];

var myPolygon=new google.maps.Polygon({map:map});

myPolygon.setPath(javascriptvariable);
```

However, I see that you have javascriptvariable enclosed in brackets. If it's on purpose, then you'd be trying to declare an array of arrays as Path (which you can't), but since a Polygon can have several paths, you can do

```
myPolygon.setPaths([javascriptvariable]);
```

which means roughly the same as the former notation.

Comment: Thanks for your fast help. I now use your second suggestion: var polygoneCoords = [{lat:49.91727104462425,...

Comment: I doesn't work first, because i have had an other error: javascriptvariable was a string and not an array, so i use nwo JSON.parse and everything works! ;)